# Zoom Google Map from different ViewController - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, zooming, google-maps-sdk-ios

**Scenario**

I have a TabBarcontroller with 2 tabs.

I have GoogleMap's Map on `ViewControllerA` (Tab 1).

I'm currently on another view controller, let's say `ViewControllerB` (Tab 2), which has a `UITableView`, and obviously, the map is not visible here.

**Problem**

Now I call a function (via delegates) in `ViewControllerA`, to zoom the map to a particular location, but it doesn't zoom it until I switch back to Tab 1. (As soon as I switch to Tab 1, the map zooms to that location in an eye's blink.

Is there anyway to zoom the map without opening that Viewcontroller?

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try using a singleton design pattern, basically create a singleton reference to the GoogleMap object and set the zoom and try:

[mapSingletonObjc setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: There's no need of singleton, when there's already just one instance of map in my project. And I'm zooming that only instance, as stated in the question, VIA DELEGATES.